# How to update options after init in egjs-flicking?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using egjs-flicking for Vue2 project.
I want it to use different `align` option on mobile and desktop screen sizes.
Is there a way to change without destroying/init?

Comment: This requires to heavily rely on the implementation, https://github.com/naver/egjs-flicking/blob/master/packages/vue-flicking/src/Flicking.ts#L60 . You can try to reach internal instance, probably it's flickingCompRef.vanillaFlickin.forceRenderAllPanels() according to this https://github.com/naver/egjs-flicking/blob/master/packages/vue-flicking/src/Flicking.ts#L62 . Re-mounting on device type sizes is a justified and less hacky option. Sometimes this case isn't even handled in web apps

Answer (score 0):

Landed on the solution like this:

1. Added on `resize` event handler with stores if it's a mobile screen in the component data, also two flags to understand its current size and if it has gone from mobile to desktop (or the other way around), and updating the `Flicking` options object to switch `align`.
2. Using `:key` on the `Flicking` component to recreate it when it's gone from  mobile to desktop (see flags above)

So after the window has gone from mobile to desktop or screen (or vice versa) the component is recreated without triggering `destroy`/`init` manually. Seems to suffice for now.